# iOS: Send GPS Location from one device to Google Maps on another?

Tags: iphone

Can you send your currently location through the iPhone SDK to another iPhone and have them open up your location in Google Maps?

The only way I can think of is through text message, but I'm not even sure that would work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be easy to set up a webserver to relay the message.

User 1's iPhone sends the phone's location to the server, which stores it in a database. User 2's iPhone periodically polls the server for the latest location of User 1 and displays it on screen.

You'd have to work out a good system of limiting which users can access whose data and so on, but otherwise it's a pretty straightforward project.